# Fullscreen image until scroll (responsive)

Tags: html, css, scroll, fullscreen, responsive

I am relatively new to HTML and CSS, however "Skill comes with practice".

I would like to create a pagescroll effect similar to this page:
[Jolla](https://jolla.com/jolla/)

The difficult thing is to get the effect on every device.
So every device should see the full picture fullscreen (don't see text below; example: don't see the "we are unlike"-stuff).
However if any device scrolls down a bit (one scrool), the picture should slide to the top and the following text should be revealed.

Hope you guys can follow me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this using css properties.

All you have to do in your html is...

```
<div></div>
```

In your css...

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
  background-image: url("rand_img.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hm didn't worked. I have to fill the <div> with content. But which content can I use that should fill the whole page? Right know I just have a blank page.

Comment: As you add comment to your div, your background should be getting larger and larger. Take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/suez/full/wulBv/) and look inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code here. There's also more in depth article by [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) that this is based off of.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Header</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="background">
    </div>

    <style>
        #background {
            background-image: url("https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1471705301355-ec78367a7b07");
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            /* Preserve aspet ratio */
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            top: -50%;
            left: -50%;
            width: 200%;
            height: 200%;
        }

    </style>

</body>
```

Be sure to keep up the good work in learning and practice, practice, practice!